# Access Django "context" in template javascript (to create markers on a Map)

Tags: python, django, leaflet

i am trying to iterate over a list of dictionares in a javascript. 
The list is coming from render context, and is called "spots". If I print "spots" this is what I see:

```
[{u'rider_ability': u'Intermediate, Expert', u'spot_distance': 0, u'water_type': u'Shallow, Flat, Chop, Small wave', u'water_quality': u'Clean', u'lat': 40.6775, u'lng': 14.7587, u'spot_name': u'Salerno'}, {u'rider_ability': u'Expert', u'spot_distance': 7, u'water_type': u'Flat, Chop, Small wave', u'water_quality': u'Clean', u'lat': 40.6436, u'lng': 14.6984, u'spot_name': u'Cetara'}, {u'rider_ability': u'Intermediate, Expert', u'spot_distance': 16, u'water_type': u'Chop, Small wave', u'water_quality': u'Crystal clear', u'lat': 40.6262, u'lng': 14.5883, u'spot_name': u'Spiaggia Duoglie'}, {u'rider_ability': u'Beginner, Intermediate, Expert', u'spot_distance': 33, u'water_type': u'Shallow, Chop, Small wave', u'water_quality': u'Clean', u'lat': 40.4271, u'lng': 14.9818, u'spot_name': u'Ponte di Ferro'}, {u'rider_ability': u'Beginner, Intermediate, Expert', u'spot_distance': 36, u'water_type': u'Shallow, Chop, Small wave', u'water_quality': u'Clean', u'lat': 40.4026, u'lng': 14.9949, u'spot_name': u'Paestum'}, {u'rider_ability': u'Beginner, Intermediate, Expert', u'spot_distance': 41, u'water_type': u'Shallow, Flat, Chop, Small wave', u'water_quality': u'Clean', u'lat': 40.343, u'lng': 14.9717, u'spot_name': u'Agropoli'}]
```

And this is the code I am trying to use (without any result, I see an empty map).

```
<script>
    const options = {
            key: 'MYKEY',
            verbose: true,
        }

    windyInit(options, windyAPI => {
        const {
            map
        } = windyAPI

        {% for spot in spots %}

            L.marker([spot.lat, spot.lng]).bindPopup(spot.spot_name).addTo(map)

        {% endfor %}
    })

</script>
```

Any idea on how to do? Many thanks.

Comment: Isn't this just a case of using `{{ spot.lat }}`, `{{ spot.lng }}` etc... to actually substitute the values into the template?

Comment: That does not work, I am really not sure on how to handle this. From the view arrives {{ spots }} that is a list of dictionaries (see values above). I can't understand how to access and iterate on it in JS. Are you sure the only problem with my code is only on {{ spot.lat }}, {{ spot.lng }}? Because this change does not work

Answer (score 0):

You are not using curly parentheses `{{ }}` to inject a variable. Just replace this:

```
[spot.lat, spot.lng]
```

with

```
[{{ spot.lat }}, {{ spot.lng }}]
```

and you are good to go. You can read more about template [variables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/templates/#variables).

Comment: This is not working... Are you sure the problem with my code is only this one? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to use xhr in javascript and convert you data to json and use HttpResponse()

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use your same code, make sure that the loop will first finished before the scripts runs, or else it will not be rendered. one more thing replace it with {{ spot.lat }} and {{ spot.lng }}. you missed the curly brackets..:-)